# How to prevent persistent naming of network interfaces, like eth1

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, debian-jessie

I have a freshly installed Debian Jessie. I had two NICs, which were eth0 and eth1, now I took out one, however I still have eth1 left in the system:

```
% dmesg
...
tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95754) rev b002] (PCI Express) MAC address 00:1a:a0:ac:f6:2d
tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5787 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
...
systemd-udevd[171]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
```

Is there a way to ask not to rename the interface and just keep eth0? Thanks.

Comment: See the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

Comment: this is a **udev** thing, not a systemd thing.

Comment: @Zoredache Sure, but udev has been swept under the systemd umbrella...